# Python object return QWidget

Tags: python, pyside

How can I get a class method to return a QWidget without throwing this error:

> QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class customParam(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Test'

    def get_widget(self):
        # widget = paramWidgets.BoolWidget(self.uid, self.value, self.label0)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        return widget


param = customParam()
param.get_widget()
```

The reason I'm doing this, I have a slew of custom parameter objects which I then will use the GetWidget method to dynamically populate the UI so users can edit the param values on the fly.

Comment: As error says, you must create a `QApplication` before trying to create a `QWidget`.

Comment: I don't understand why that matters. im not displaying it anywhere. not yet

Comment: Because the `QApplication` sets up internal resources that are required by all gui-related objects (e.g. widgets, pixmaps, etc). That's just the way qt works.

Comment: alright then thanks

Comment: The [Detailed Description for QApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#details) lists some of the most important things it does when initialising an application. It seems pretty clear why you can't construct a paint-device before all that has been set up.